# Biblatex - Undefined control sequence when reading bibtex-file

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, texshop

I get hundreds of these errors when I'm trying to compile a bibliography:

```
./Megumi oppgave.aux:57: Undefined control sequence.
l.57 ... Morgen}}{{Aftenposten Morgen}}{{\APACyear
                                                   {1987}}}}
./Megumi oppgave.aux:59: Undefined control sequence.
l.59 \APACbibcite
                 {AftenpostenMorgen1989}{\citeauthoryear {{Aftenposten Morge...

./Megumi oppgave.aux:59: Undefined control sequence.
l.59 ...ite{AftenpostenMorgen1989}{\citeauthoryear
                                                   {{Aftenposten Morgen}}{{A...
```

This is basically my document setup:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside, titlepage]{article}       
\usepackage{geometry}                       
\geometry{a4paper}                          
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[tc]{titlepic}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{path/library.bib} 



\title{xx
}



\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents


\section{Some title}
This text is cited \cite{Moene2009f}.


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I've had great trouble trying to export my Endnote library including attachments to bibtex. I therefore use the bibtex library published by Mandeley, which seems like a good solution. Here's an excerpt from the bibtex file. It seems like the file is being read in alphabetical order when run.

```
@article{Atack2002,
author = {Atack, Iain},
journal = {Security Dialogue},
number = {3},
pages = {279--292},
title = {{Ethical Objectives to Humanitarian Intervention}},
volume = {33},
year = {2002}
}
@article{Kabashima2000,
author = {Kabashima, Ikuo and Marshall, Jonathan and Uekami, Takayoshi and Hyun, Dae-``Song},
journal = {Political Psychology},
keywords = {survey, data collected from national public survey},
number = {4},
pages = {779--804},
title = {{Casual cynics or disillusioned democrats? Political alienation in Japan}},
volume = {21 },
year = {2000}
}
@book{Aakvaag2008,
address = {Oslo},
author = {Aakvaag, Gunnar C},
publisher = {Abstrakt},
title = {{Moderne sosiologisk teori}},
year = {2008}
}
@incollection{Hall1997,
address = {London},
author = {Hall, Stuart},
booktitle = {Cultural representations and signifying practices},
editor = {Hall, Stuart},
publisher = {Sage},
title = {{Representation, meaning and language}},
year = {1997}
```

I would appreciate any help!

EDIT:
Thank you to the two first answers. I've set biber as the driver in TexShop's preferences and defined the correct language. It now seems to read the bib-file correctly. However, I get another error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Hurd1999' on page 1 undefined on input line 49.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 56.

[1] (./Megumi oppgave.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                "Megumi oppgave"
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Comment: Note that the APA style for `biblatex` requires you to use `biber` as the backend, which your example seems to use, but `biber` does *not* read the `.aux` file, but the `.bcf` file.  Have you (also?) tried to run `bibtex` or something?  (As an aside, I recommend avoiding spaces in filenames -- even though that's not the problem here.)

Comment: Thank you! It seems like it now reads the file properly. But I got a new problem, as quoted in the edit above.

Comment: To make sure things are working, delete all associated files (`.aux`, `.bcf`, `.bbl`, etc.), run `latex` on the file (`latex Megumi oppgave.tex` [note you will need to escape the spaces however that's done in your OS]), then run `biber Megumi oppgave.bcf` (escaping spaces again), then `latex Megumi oppgave.tex`.  We're using the file extensions just to be extra sure that all is being done correctly -- normally it's not needed.  If that `latex-biber-latex` sequence doesn't work, then we need to look more widely for the source of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `biblatex-apa` style uses many customisations and most of them are language specific. 
To load the a specific language you have to use

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{norsk}{norsk-apa}
```

See section 3.2 of the manual (`texdoc biblatex-apa` from the command line)